# Using GPU Acceleration in ANSYS Mechanical

Tags: ansys, ansys-workbench, ansys-apdl

I am attempting to solve ANSYS mechanical (via workbench) using GPU acceleration, but I keep getting the following error:

> *** WARNING ***                         CP =      79.594   TIME= 15:40:08
>    The GPU accelerator capability is not valid when using the memory
>    saving option (MSAVE command) for the PCG solver.  The GPU accelerator
>    capability is disabled for this solution.

How can I turn off the MSAVE option? It seems to be default for a model this size and I cannot find the way to turn it off.

I am using V19.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in the end with a lucky guess:

[image]

Simply enter "MSAVE, off" into the command line arguments in the advanced solver settings.

Comment: Thank you for posting it, for which type of problems GPU is better, and do I need to install a GPU like hardware or have sth on my system ?

Comment: Yes, you need to have a GPU hardware installed on your system to do this. The GPU is used to factorise matrices only it seems, so the more matrix operations your solution requires, in theory the better benefit you will see. I saw that decent size meshes (10m+ elements) that require lots of steps to converge saw the biggest improvement over our CPU-only solve times. I compared 8 CPUs cores with 7 CPU cores + 1GPU as these two setups use the same number of licenses. In very simple models with few matrix operations, solutions were the same or marginally slower with the GPU due to 1 less CPU core.